# `<canvas width="1024" height="768">` Does the browser, the web server or something else automatically add the extra line of HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code consists of 2 parts: `index.html` and `game.js`.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above doesn't specify the width and height for the canvas though, when I inspected the page I got, I saw an extra line of HTML

```
<canvas width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
```

Who does put it in there? Does the browser, the web server or something else automatically add the extra line of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put my money on the script you're requesting in your header:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

That contains the code:

```
/*** 
@const {(number|string)} Phaser.Core.Config#width - The width of the underlying canvas, in pixels.
*/
        this.width = GetValue(config, 'width', 1024);

/*** 
@const {(number|string)} Phaser.Core.Config#height - The height of the underlying canvas, in pixels. 
*/
        this.height = GetValue(config, 'height', 768);
```

So, to answer your question, it is the browser.